# Deploying react app using fabricjs causing error in functionality

Tags: reactjs, canvas, deployment, fabricjs, netlify

I'm trying to deploy a React app using fabricjs. On localhost it's working fine but after deploying , fabric functions not working and causing an error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'add')`
[what can be the issue ? and if anyone know it what can be the possible solution ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdQlt.png)

here is the code for adding text box to the fabric canvas

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
import ContextCanvas from '../../../context/ContextCanvas';
import { Button } from '@chakra-ui/react';

const FabricTextBox = () => {
  const [canvas] = useContext(ContextCanvas);
  function addTextBox() {
    const textbox = new fabric.Textbox('Click on the Rectangle to move it.', {
      fontSize: 20,
      left: 50,
      top: 100,
      width: 200,
      fill: 'black',
      color: 'white',
      cornerColor: 'blue',

    });
    canvas.add(textbox);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        type="button"
        colorScheme="blue"
        onClick={addTextBox}
        variant={'ghost'}
        _hover={{}}
        _focus={{}}
        _active={{}}
        textColor={'white'}
        fontWeight={'light'}
      >
        Text Field
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default FabricTextBox;
```

here is my fabric canvas

```
import React, { useContext, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
import ContextCanvas from '../../context/ContextCanvas';


const FabricCanvas = () => {
  const [canvas, initCanvas] = useContext(ContextCanvas);


  useLayoutEffect(() => {

    return () => {
      initCanvas(new fabric.Canvas('c'));
    };
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      <canvas
        id="c"
        width={window.innerWidth}
        height={window.innerHeight}
      />
    </>
  )
}
export default FabricCanvas;
```

here is my context provider

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const ContextCanvas = createContext();

export function CanvasProvider({ children }) {
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState(null);
  const initCanvas = c => {
    setCanvas(c);
    c.renderAll();
  };

  return (
    <ContextCanvas.Provider value={[canvas, initCanvas]}>
      {children}
    </ContextCanvas.Provider>
  );
}

export default ContextCanvas;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the solution of the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73032118/why-im-getting-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-add