# Why I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'add') on deployment?

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs, use-context

[image]

I'm working on a editor app using fabric.js.On localhost, When i click on Add Circle it works fine while on deployment it is causing cannot read properties of null.

Here is the code:

I'm using react context api by which i add objects in canvas and it displays on screen.

FabricCircle.js

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
import ContextCanvas from '../../../context/ContextCanvas';
import { Button } from '@chakra-ui/react';

const FabricTextBox = () => {
  const [canvas] = useContext(ContextCanvas);
  function addTextBox() {
    const textbox = new fabric.Textbox('Click on the Rectangle to move it.', {
      fontSize: 20,
      left: 50,
      top: 100,
      width: 200,
      fill: 'black',
      color: 'white',
      cornerColor: 'blue',

    });
    canvas.add(textbox);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        type="button"
        colorScheme="blue"
        onClick={addTextBox}
        variant={'ghost'}
        _hover={{}}
        _focus={{}}
        _active={{}}
        textColor={'white'}
        fontWeight={'light'}
      >
        Text Field
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default FabricTextBox;
```

FabricCanvas.js

```
import React, { useContext, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
import ContextCanvas from '../../context/ContextCanvas';


const FabricCanvas = () => {
  const [canvas, initCanvas] = useContext(ContextCanvas);


  useLayoutEffect(() => {

    return () => {
      initCanvas(new fabric.Canvas('c'));
    };
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      <canvas
        id="c"
        width={window.innerWidth}
        height={window.innerHeight}
      />
    </>
  )
}
export default FabricCanvas;
```

ContextCanvas.js

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const ContextCanvas = createContext();

export function CanvasProvider({ children }) {
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState(null);
  const initCanvas = c => {
    setCanvas(c);
    c.renderAll();
  };

  return (
    <ContextCanvas.Provider value={[canvas, initCanvas]}>
      {children}
    </ContextCanvas.Provider>
  );
}

export default ContextCanvas;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is related to this line in `FabricCircle.js`

```
canvas.add(textbox);
      ^^^^
```

because your canvas object is `null` *in production*.

---

### Assuming you use `React.StrictMode`

Using [`React.StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state)

> With Strict Mode starting in React 18, whenever a component mounts in development, React will simulate immediately unmounting and remounting the component:

*Strict mode flow ([read more](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state))*

```
* React mounts the component.
    * Layout effects are created.
    * Effect effects are created.
* React simulates effects being destroyed on a mounted component.
    * Layout effects are destroyed. [THIS]
    * Effects are destroyed.
* React simulates effects being re-created on a mounted component.
    * Layout effects are created
    * Effect setup code runs
```

> *The step marked with `[THIS]` is what makes you feel all right in the local environment (but it's an illusion... See why in the next section).*

---

###### With that been said:

Your canvas is initialized `null` inside `useState` and in the `useLayoutEffect`, you are calling the `initCanvas` method **inside the** [**cleanup function**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1) (so it will only be called when it's too late in production, while in development with StrictMode act like an init-function although it's a cleanup function).

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {

    // Your code should be here

    return () => { // The returned function is the cleanup function

      // This is executed only when disposing the component.
      initCanvas(new fabric.Canvas('c'));
      // But when strict mode is active 
      //  the component is disposed and re-mounted immidiatly.
    };
}, []);
```

> This is why the local environment works and the production environment doesn't.

#### Solution

*Try updating your `useLayoutEffect` like this:*

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
   initCanvas(new fabric.Canvas('c'));
}, []);
```

---

#### Conclusion

You should not initialize your state inside a cleanup function.

In this case, `React.StrictMode` behavior prevents you from realizing the error (*without strict mode, it wouldn't even work in development*).

Since you were initializing the canvas inside the cleanup function, the canvas never get initialized in time (without the strict mode), remaining `null`, as the error you receive states.

Comment: Yes it works. I removed the strict mode and return from useLayoutEffect

Comment: Great! Once the `useLayoutEffect` is fixed you shouldn't have any problems with StrictMode anyway :) Of course if you don't care you can remove it, but it's not mandatory.